# Remove Click Handler-GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2

How to remove the ClickHandler Event in GWT? I added addClickHandler() Event for a button and i want to remove the ClickHandler Event.I tried HandlerRegistration Method But it failed to remove the handler ,Here is a snippet :

```
notification.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });
```

I want to remove the handler with notification !

```
Note:
Notification is the button instance that calls the handler!
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it fails` and `remove the handler with notification`?

Comment: Fails refers to HandlerEvent is not removed and i have mentioned notification as button instance that calls the handler !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Each `add...Handler` method returns the `HandlerRegistration` interface. This interface contains the `removeHandler()` method. If you want to remove handlers, simple store the returned interface in a variable and call removeHandler when you want to remove the handler.

```
HandlerRegistration handler;

handler = button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // ...

            }
        });
handler.removeHandler();
```

Comment: Can I get the handler object to remove later? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I get the Handler registration when I bind the event,

```
closeIconHandlerRegistration = closeImg.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick( ClickEvent event )
            {
                addCloseClickHanlder();
            }
        } );
```

After that When I need to remove the handler...

```
if ( this.getCloseButtonHandlerRegistration() != null )
        {
            this.getCloseButtonHandlerRegistration().removeHandler();
            this.getCloseImg().addClickHandler( new ClickHandler()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick( ClickEvent event )
                {
                    SaveCancelCommissionChangeEvent saveEvt = new SaveCancelCommissionChangeEvent();
                    saveEvt.setSave( false );
                    tabEventBus.fireEvent( saveEvt );
                }
            } );
        }
```